# How do tools like iperf measure UDP?

Tags: performance, udp, measure

Given that UDP packets don't actually send acks, how does a program like iperf measure their one-way performance, i.e., how can it confirm that the packets actually reached:

- within a time frame
- intact, and uncorrupted

To contrast, Intuitively, to me, it seems that TCP packets, which have an ack signal sent back to allow rigorous benchmarking of their movement across a network can be done very reliably from a client.

Answer (score 2):

**1/ "how can it confirm that the packets actually reached [...] intact, and uncorrupted"**

UDP is an unfairly despised protocol, but come on, this is going way too far here! :-)

UDP have checksum, just like TCP:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#Checksum_computation

**2/ "how can it confirm that the packets actually reached [...] within a time frame"**

It does not, because this is not what UDP is about, nor TCP by the way.[*]

As can be seen from its source code here:

https://github.com/esnet/iperf/blob/master/src/iperf_udp.c#L55

...what it does though, is check for out of order packets. A "pcount" is set in the sending side, and checked at the receiving side here:

https://github.com/esnet/iperf/blob/master/src/iperf_udp.c#L99

...and somewhat calculate a bogus jitter:

https://github.com/esnet/iperf/blob/master/src/iperf_udp.c#L110

(real life is more complicated than this, you not only have jitter, but also drift)

[*]:

- For semi-garanteed, soft "within a time frame" / real time layer 3 and above protocols, look at RTP, RTSP and such. But neither TCP nor UDP inherently have this.
- For real, serious hard real-time garantee, you've got to go to layer 2 protocols such as Ethernet-AVB:
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Video_Bridging
  ...which were designed because IP and above simply cannot. make. hard. real. time. guaranteed. delivery. Period.

EDIT:

This is another debate, but...

The first thing you need for "within a time frame", is a shared wall clock on sending/receiving systems (else, how could you tell that such received packet is out of date?)

From Layer 3 (IP) and above, `NTP` precision target is about 1ms. It can be less than that on a LAN (but accross IP networks, it's just taking a chance and hope the best).

On layer 2, aka "LAN" the layer 2 `PTP` (Precision Time Protocol) `IEEE 1588` is for sub-microsecond range. **That's a 1000 times more accurate**. Same goes for the derived `IEEE 802.1AS`, "Timing and Synchronization for Time-Sensitive Applications (gPTP)" used In Ethernet AVB.

Conclusion on this sub-topic:

TCP/IP, though very handy and powerful, is not *designed* to "guarantee delivery within a time frame". Be it TCP or UDP. Get this idea out of your head.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way would be to connect to a server that participates in the testing.

The client starts by (for example) connecting to an NTP server to get an accurate time base.

Then the UDP client sends a series of packets to the server. In its payload, each packet contains:

1. a serial number
2. a timestamp when it was sent
3. a CRC

The server then looks these over and notes whether any serial numbers are missing (after some reasonable timeout) and compares the time it received each packet to the time the client sent the packet. After some period of time, the server sends a reply indicating how many packets it received, the mean and standard deviation of the transmission times, and an indication of how many appeared to be corrupted based on the CRCs they contained.

Depending on taste, you might also want to set up a simultaneous TCP connection from the client to the server to coordinate testing of the UDP channel and (possibly) return results.